# Src attribute in golang templates

Tags: javascript, html, web, go

When executing template on golang server, I got an issue that src attribute in html file searches for importing javascript file not in the root location (server folder), but below the handled url. So, requesting `src='/dir/file.js'` having current location like `http://localhost:8080/handled/` will make GET request for `http://localhost:8080/handled/dir/file.js`.

```
package main

import ("net/http"; "html/template")

var templates = template.Must(template.ParseFiles("././dir/file.html"))

type Page struct {
  Title string
  Body  []byte
}

func testHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
  page := Page{"handled", nil}

  err := templates.ExecuteTemplate(w, "file.html", p)
  if err != nil {
    http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
  }
}

func main() {
  http.HandleFunc("/handled/", testHandler)
  http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
}
```

So, the template file.html contains the following line:

```
<!-- file.html
javascript placed right inside template file is working,
but I didnt managed to get to work src insertation -->
<script src="file.js"></script>
```

...the file.js sharing the same directory with file.html.
I tried different file locations and various paths combinations. Seems like I'm doing it a wrong way.

Comment: What HTTP server is serving `file.js?` From the posted code, there's no `http.FileServer` serving the static content (JS, CSS, etc) from the same directory as your template files. If this is the case, no variation of paths will fix it: the static content isn't "implicitly" served just because it's in the same directory as your template files. (and for future ref, a leading slash is the best way to go - avoid relative URLs at all costs).

Answer (score 1):

If your browser is requesting /handled/dir/file.js then your src must be missing the initial forward slash.  This is not a Go specific problem.

I see that you say your file being requested has src="/dir/file.js", but then in your example you show src="file.js", so I am not exactly sure what you really have.  However, your problem is still indicative of forgetting the first slash, like src="dir/file.js"

Comment: There is no forward slash in the path. So, requested file must be searched locally, isn't it? Seems like it doesn't, that's why I posted a question.
The reason I added it above is to show that GET requests are sent below handled url. Thats it.

Comment: If you don't have a forward slash then the request path is relative.  You either need to make it correctly relative with src="../dir/file.js", absolute with src="/dir/file.js" or you need to set the html `base` tag (http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_base.asp) to set the base and leave it as you have it

Comment: Javascript inserted via relative path actually causes 'syntax error' showed in browser console. But the script contains only 'alert("testing!");'. When I look into error message info it only shows the script tag with src attr. As stated on top, both files located in same directory, so its not like I get messed up with include paths (also tried dozens of variations, even absolute ones).

Comment: See my comment on your question. Just because `file.js` is in the same directory as `file.html` (a html/template template), it does not mean it is "accessible". Only templates are parsed by `template.ParseFiles`.